# FilpickerIO web API security policy and publicly accessible files

Tags: filepicker.io

I have just started reading your [docs on security and policy generation](https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/security/) after realising that files could easily be deleted with the *API key* and a `DELETE` request. Your security implementation seems to be the answer to protecting our users files (images in this case) and rendering the API key useless for file writes. 
However, before I implement security, I have some questions:

I want all images to be publicly accessible, i.e. policy ?call=read. 
Is there a way to setup a default read-only policy so that files are publicly accessible without having to generate a policy for every url? (or am I misunderstanding)

I would ideally like to serve images with an url of `https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/[handle]` and write/remove images by generating the policy for authenticated users (and for API calls on the backend).

*EDIT: Unfortunately Liyan's answer is not optimal for me as I could have 100's of images each requiring hard-coded query strings to be appended after being loaded from the db. The solution from my perspective is to have a checkbox (for now and a default policy editor later) in the developer portal which would allow you to set read only access for 'default' urls. Is that (or something similar) something the filepicker.io guys/gals would consider adding? Otherwise the extra maintenance and complexity of having url processing between my db and views is a bit of a nightmare.*

*EDIT: Well Filepicker.io have shown once again what a great service they offer! Big thank you to Liyan and the rest of the team for those changes. I will recommend you guys to whoever I can :)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now set your urls as "Read Only" in your developer portal.

Comment: Ummm ;) Am I using it correctly? It does not seem to be working. My example url: `https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/lRRtsexbS1ODs4Fn6bAk`

Comment: The "read only" flag means if you don't have security on, to turn off the ability to write/delete links. What you want is simlarbut the reverse approach of having security and whitelisting. I'll take another look at how to do it right in a couple days. Feel free to email me liyan@filepicker.io to talk about it offline.

Comment: Thanks Liyan, I see the approach taken now - I'll send an email to discuss the issue further.

Answer (score 0):

Specify an expiry and a call. Then don't specify a handle.

```
{'call': ['read', 'convert'], 'expiry': expiryForNextHundredYears}
```

That policy would allow a read, convert for all your files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So currently no way to set a default policy for "unsigned" urls - is that something filepicker.io would consider adding?

Comment: Noticed that the docs have the debug/security example url and 'live' url swapped around [here](https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/security/#debug) and when using the /debug/security endpoint the following message always appears *This app does not have the ability to secure urls.*

Comment: Yes. There is a typo there. It should be remove

Comment: I'm not sure if you are answering points 1,2 and 3 or just my last point ;) I was not able to curl a DELETE request with {call:['remove']} but {call:['revoke']} works.

Comment: You should now be able to do it with call remove. It was a typo in our code that I've now resolved. 'revoke' will still work, but 'remove' is the right way of doing it. Thanks for your help with this.